# Prepending an item to the top of the list with Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, list, prepend

I have a simple app that adds an item to a list, but the item gets added to the bottom of the list rather than the top. Is there a way to get it adding to the top such as prepending it? Let me know if you need more code to look at. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

The HTML

```
<!-- LOOP OVER THE TODOS IN $scope.todos -->
            <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="todo in todos">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="deleteTodo(todo._id)"> {{ todo.text }}
                </label>
            </div>
```

Some of the Angular.js

```
// when submitting the add form, send the text to the node API
    $scope.createTodo = function() {
        $scope.loading = true;

        // validate the formData to make sure that something is there
        // if form is empty, nothing will happen
        if ($scope.formData.text != undefined) {

            // call the create function from our service (returns a promise object)
            Todos.create($scope.formData)

                // if successful creation, call our get function to get all the new todos
                .success(function(data) {
                    $scope.loading = false;
                    $scope.formData = {}; // clear the form so our user is ready to enter another
                    $scope.todos = data; // assign our new list of todos
                });
        }
    };

// create todo and send back all todos after creation
app.post('/api/todos', function(req, res) {

    // create a todo, information comes from AJAX request from Angular
    Todo.create({
        text : req.body.text,
        done : false
    }, function(err, todo) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        // get and return all the todos after you create another
        Todo.find(function(err, todos) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err)
            res.json(todos);
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: `todos.unshift(todo)`

Comment: Do I put that in my createTodo function?

Comment: It just keeps saying that todos is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting the answer after some more information was obtained from the comments.

The problem is that the todos is an object rather than an array. In Angular, when iterating (ng-repeat) over an object the keys of the objects are used to determine the order of the items. This is typically not what you want when dealing with lists of things (todos). So the way to approach this would be to change the back-end so that it returns an array.

I won't go too much into mongodb details on how this is done, but generally you may either store each todo as its own document and return a get on all the documents, or you can store one document with a todos property (which is a BsonArray) and return that document.

Comment: I use mongoDB as my database. Is the way it is being stored in mongoDB?

Comment: You need to inspect your todos variable. Is it an Array or an Object? If it's an object with a property for each todo, then angular will order the items according to the keys. If it's an array, then mongoDB is not at fault.

Comment: It is being stored as an Object.

Comment: Aha.. then that's your answer then. You probably want your items stored in an array so that the order can be significant.

Comment: Well each todo has its own ID associated with it.

Comment: var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Todo', {
 text : String,
 done : Boolean
});

Comment: Rewrote my anser. Please accept my answer if it got you closer to a solution, and post a new question if you require more mongodb help. I'm not the right person to help you with that, I don't think. (very limited experience with it.)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I need to rewrite my question now that I know there is more to it.

Comment: If you are still around this is what the object looks like. { "text" : "Funky Town", "done" : false, "_id" : { "$oid" : "53c022617712140000000001" }, "__v" : 0 }

Comment: That's the todo, not the todos. Your todo should be an object and your todos should be an array of several todo's.

Comment: Hmm okay. That's the JSON I get back when I export the database.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by exporting your database. But what you should care about is what the http-response of your datarequest contains. Meaning the response text of your server call as seen in the network tab of chrome (or whatever). If adding an item returns that item as you showed, that's ok. But when you get the initial todos that needs to be an array

Comment: It is returning everything correctly. I just have to wait 90 mins before I can post my updated question. I am trying to get unshift() to work, but it just keeps returning todos as undefined.

Comment: Array.prototype.unshift doesn't return a new Array. It returns the new length of the modified Array. In short, don't do $scope.todos = $scope.todos.unshift(todo). Rather simply do $scope.todos.unshift(todo) (without the assignment).

Comment: I understand that. (todo) keeps coming back as undefined. Do I have to pass todo into a function? I really appreciate the time you have spent on this already.

Comment: I'm assuming you're refering to the todo inside the Todo.create second argument function. If that's the case then it's hard for me to tell since I don't know how you coded the Todo service. Potentially app.post might be causing your application to reload or some weird stuff. Looks a bit inverted how you create the new todo inside the callback of a post rather than the app.post as a continuation after Todo.create is done.